# Fitting a UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to resize my `UIImage` according to the size of `UIImageView`. My image is too small, so i need to scale it up. I was not able to do it using:

```
self.firstImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you try the other content modes?

Comment: yes.. i tried.. but none of the modes were working for me.. however @vineet's suggestion solved my problem..

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 3.0** , it will be

```
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize ) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.width))
    let newImage : UIImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
self.imageView.contentMode   = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: clipsToBounds is a UIView property and UIImageView extends UIView.

Comment: typo: should be clipsToBounds instead of clipToBounds