# make UIImage AspectFit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, pdf-generation

I am generating PDF with image and problem is that

```
 [imageview.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

in generated PDF my image got stretched to size we define in `CGRectMake`  so how can my image set to Aspect Fit not UIImageView ?

my size is fixed 100*100 in PDF but image need to aspectFit

Any help ?

Comment: Can you add the code of how you are converting it into PDF?

Comment: @ankit UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 880), nil); via this

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do. It will maintain the aspect ratio of whatever you want to add in a block.

Calculate the size of the image and then add in the CGRect.

`CGRect AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(CGSize aspectRatio, CGRect boundingRect);`

For more information check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerectwithaspectratioinsider)

Comment: tried but when drawinrect with 100*100 image for streched because it is not possible to [imageview drawInRect  only [imageview.image drawInRect possible

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set contentmode of your imageview , where the content of view(image) changes when views bound changes

for ex:
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Refer:
contentmode in apple documentation

Comment: UIImageview is not needed. I want with UIImage.

Comment: check with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882567/fitting-a-uiimage-in-uiimageview